# Is this a correct proof that these two norms are not equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Consider $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_1)$ and $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_2)$ where the norms are

$$ \|f\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f(x)| dx$$

and

$$ \|f\|_2 = \left (\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx \right )^{1\over 2}$$

> I tried to show that these are not equivalent, please could someone
>   tell me if this is correct reasoning?

We recall that two norms are equivalent if and only if there exist constants $A,B$ such that
$a \|x\| \le \|x\|' \le b\|x\|$ for all $x$ in the normed space. Hence it is enough to find one $x$ for which no such constants can exist:

To this end consider $f(x) = {1\over \sqrt{x}}$. We have

$$ \|f\|_1 = \sqrt{1} = 1$$
 but

$$ \|f\|_2 = \infty$$

hence $\|\cdot\|_1 $ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ cannot be equivalnet.

Comment: Nope. Your proof is incorrect. Your example, $f$, is not an element of $C[0,1]$.

Comment: @5xum Oops, you're right. Not sure how I could miss that. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: You should immediatelly think "wait, that's not right" if you have a normed space and an element with an infinite norm. That tells you that either the norm is not a norm or the element is not really in the space.

Comment: @5xum Thank you, indeed, that is an excellent remark!

Comment: @5xum But wait, the space is the space of continuous functions. So $f$ is an element of the space!

Comment: No, not on the closed interval it isn't

Comment: @5xum Yeah, sorry, it was a little late when I wrote that. So, basically to solve this I want a sequence that is bounded in one norm but unbounded in the other, right?

Answer (score 4):

Take $f_n\in C[0,1] $ $$f_n (t) =\begin{cases} -2n^2 t +2n \mbox{ if } 0\leqslant t<n^{-1} \\ 0 \hspace{2cm} \mbox{ if } n^{-1}\leqslant t\leqslant 1 \end{cases} .$$
Then $||f_n ||_1=1 $ but $||f_n ||_2 =\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3} \cdot \sqrt{n} \to\infty$ so the norms are not equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Note also $\|x^n\|_1 = 1/(n+1), \|x^n\|_2 = 1/\sqrt {(2n+1)}.$

Comment: This has been downvoted by three people and upvoted by three people.  I wonder if any of the downvoters would like to explain why?